# Missing space in biblatex-chicago bibliographies for articles without number entries

Tags: biblatex, chicago-style

I'm searching for a fix for a problem with biblatex-chicago's authordate-styled bibliographies. They omit the space between the `volume` and `pages` fields if `article` entries lack a `number` (issue) field. Find a MWE and printout below.

Thanks a lot.

```
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel,csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,authordate]{biblatex-chicago}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
  @ARTICLE{adams1887,
    author = {Adams, Henry Carter},
    title = {Relation of the State to Industrial Action},
    journaltitle = {Publications of the American Economic Association},
    date = {1887},
    volume = {1},
    number = {6},
    pages = {7--85}
    }  
  @ARTICLE{clark1887,
    author = {Clark, John B.},
    title = {The Limits of Competition},
    journaltitle = {Political Science Quarterly},
    date = {1887},
    pages = {45--61},
    volume = {2}
    }
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Example.
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: print]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It seems to me that the space is *added* when there is a `number` field, but the lack of uniformity is evident anyway.

Comment: Thanks! I'd rather omit the `number` (issue) fields altogether. Colons without spaces after them look like plain formatting errors to me.

Comment: This should either be checked in *CMS* 16th ed. and/or brought to the attention of the package author (who is very responsive to emails).

Comment: +1 for the answer of @moewe below, but it is worth noting that, at least in the 15th edition of the *CMS* (which is the only one I own), the seen behaviour is correct.  (Why?  I have no idea, for it is surely inconsistent --- but I find CMS annoying that way, especially as I am often forced to use it!)

Comment: And the same is explicitly true of the 16th edition (see § 14.186).  I suppose the `cms@postposit` toggle is meant to allow `biblatex-chicago` bend to the demands of French typography.

Comment: Adding to jon's update: Indeed, 14.186 of CMS 16th recommends "When page numbers immediately follow a volume number, separated only by a colon, no space follows the colon." It does so in the context of a `notes` styled bibliography, however, in which `date` information is printed in parentheses between `volume` and `pages` information, adding "when parenthetical information intervenes, a space follows the colon."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @jon and @timur have pointed out in the comments to the question, the Chicago Manual of Style (in the 15th and 16th edition) prescribes this rule.

The `biblatex-chicago` package, of course, follows the rules set by the CMS as closely as possible.

Newer versions of `biblatex-chicago` have the commands `\journalpagespunct` and `\postvolpunct` to configure the behaviour of the punctuation here. (Note that only `\postvolpunct` is documented in the manual. So you may technically not be able to rely on `\journalpagespunct` doing what it does.)

To quote from the `biblatex-chicago` documentation for `\postvolpunct`

> The Manual (14.116) unequivocally prescribes that when a volume number appears immediately before a page number, “the abbreviation vol. is omitted and a colon separates the volume number from the page number with no intervening space.”
> The treatment is basically the same whether the citation is of a book or of a periodical, and it appears to be a surprising and unwelcome feature for many users, conflicting as it may do with established typographic traditions in a number of contexts.
> Clea F. Rees requested a way to customize this, so I have provided the `\postvolpunct` command, which prints the punctuation between a volume number and a page number.
> It is set to \addcolon by default, except when the current language of the entry is French, in which case it defaults to `\addcolon\addspace`.
> You can use `\renewcommand{\postvolpunct}{...}` in your preamble to redefine it, but please note that the command only applies in this limited
> context, not more generally to the punctuation that appears between, e.g., a volume and a part field.

```
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel,csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,authordate]{biblatex-chicago}

\renewcommand*{\journalpagespunct}{\addcolon\space}
\renewcommand*{\postvolpunct}{\addcolon\space}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE{adams1887,
  author       = {Adams, Henry Carter},
  title        = {Relation of the State to Industrial Action},
  journaltitle = {Publications of the American Economic Association},
  date         = {1887},
  volume       = {1},
  number       = {6},
  pages        = {7--85},
}  
@ARTICLE{clark1887,
  author  = {Clark, John B.},
  title   = {The Limits of Competition},
  journal = {Political Science Quarterly},
  date    = {1887},
  pages   = {45--61},
  volume  = {2},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Example.
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Adams, Henry Carter. 1887. “Relation of the State to Industrial Action.” Publications of the American Economic Association 1 (6): 7–85. Clark, John B. 1887. “The Limits of Competition.” Political Science Quarterly 2: 45–61.]